# Java Homework trouble asterisks

Tags: java

I am having trouble coding. Im trying to make a program that will ask a user to input height and width for a shape. Considering I am taking a java class, I am a newbie. There needs to be two parallel shape of asterisks, can be a square or rectangle.

Thanks!

The code I have so far is kinda frankensteined in

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rectangle {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int recHeight = 0;
        int recWidth = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter height [-1 to quit] >> ");
            recHeight = input.nextInt();

            if (recHeight == -1) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

                /* check if number is valid */
            if (recHeight < 2 || recHeight > 24) {
                System.err.println("--Error: please enter a valid number");
                continue; // prompt again

                System.out.print("Enter width [-1 to quit] >> ");
                recWidth = input.nextInt();

                if (recWidth == -1) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                /* check if number is valid */
                if (recWidth < 2 || recWidth > 24) {
                    System.err.println("--Error: please enter a valid number");
                    continue; // prompt again
                }
                for (int col = 0; col < recHeight; col++) {
                    for (int row = 0; row < recWidth; row++) {
                        /* First or last row ? */
                        if (row == 0 || row == recWidth - 1) {
                            System.out.print("*");
                            if (row == recWidth - 1) {
                                System.out.println(); // border reached start a new line
                            }
                        } else { /* Last or first column ? */
                            if (col == recHeight - 1 || col == 0) {
                                System.out.print("*");
                                if (row == recWidth - 1) {
                                    System.out.println();
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.print(" ");
                                if (row == recWidth - 1) {
                                    System.out.println();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? What result you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what they are teaching you with the if and continue's. I think you created an endless loop with do while(true) because you never set it to false. 
Here is how we were taught last week, or at least modified to what you need.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareDisplay
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // scanner creation
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        // get width
        System.out.print("Enter an integer in the range of 1-24: ");
        int side = stdin.nextInt();
        // check for < 1 or greather then 24

        while( (side < 1) || (side > 24))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer in the range of 1-24: ");
            // reget the side
             side = stdin.nextInt();
        }
        // get height
        System.out.print("Enter an integer in the range of 1-24: ");
        int height = stdin.nextInt();
        // check for < 1 or greather then 24

        while( (height < 1) || (height > 24))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer in the range of 1-24: ");
            // reget the height
            height = stdin.nextInt();
        }
        // create rows
        for( int rows = 0; rows < side; rows++)
        {
            // creat cols
            for( int cols = 0; cols < height; cols++)
            {
                System.out.print("X");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll want to use `try-with-resources` with the scanner, just as a general good practise

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you want, and also covers the case they input an invalid number such as `example`

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareDisplay {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            final int columns = getInRange(input, 1, 24);
            final int rows = getInRange(input, 1, 24);
            for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    private static int getInRange(final Scanner input, final int min, final int max) {
        int returnValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        do {
            System.out.printf("Please enter a value between %d and %d: ", min, max);
            try {
                returnValue = input.nextInt();
            } catch (final InputMismatchException ignored) {
                // Ignore, keep asking
            }
            input.nextLine();
        } while (returnValue < min || returnValue > max);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

## Optimisations

- Using `try-with-resources` to handle resource management
- Extracting reading the number to reduce duplication
- Handling the `InputMismatchException` to stop it killing the program